# Connecting Android to live Website for database calls

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, eclipse

I am currently developing an android application using eclipse and I already have a website developed in PHP and MySQL, can some one guide me how to connect to my website database through android for exchanging data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest, but maybe not so elegant way to do it, is writing special php-scripts for the queries, sending http requests from the android-app to these scripts and getting the results as json-arrays.

Check out this: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

You need a Webservice Written Using [REST](http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/) Protocol or [SOAP](http://ecet.ecs.ru.acad.bg/cst06/docs/cp/siii/iiia.10.pdf) protocol or [SimpleXML](http://cdatazone.org/talks/php_works_2006/adv_xml_and_web_srv.ppt)....

Using any of the above three links you may communicate throught Mysql DB to interact ur Android App Requests

To connect the Android Application to Webservices below given Two Links could be helpful

[Android App Development and Web Server Interactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122841/android-app-development-and-web-server-interactions)

[interacting with web services and android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602024/interacting-with-web-services-and-android)

> **UPDATED**

Below Link Might be most helpful to you.. chk it

[Connection to DB from Android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415467/connecting-to-mysql-database-using-php-from-an-android-device)

Comment: I am using Apache server which uses REST protocol

Comment: If ur Using Apache server in that Case RESTful PHP webservices the lib you need to use

Comment: check this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/